# Why navbar bootstrap with third level don't work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have navbar Bootstrap with third level that open on hover on desktop. In mobile,it's must open on click. Second level works perfect. Third level - it's my pain. 
I realy need help... 
Demo http://demo1.webmaestro.com.ua

```
                    
                        
                            Про фірму 
                            
                            
                                Про нас
                                Корисна інформація
                            
                        

                        
                            Продукція
                                
                                    
                                        Фасади, цоколі
                                    
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                                Підвіконня
                                                
                                                    
                                                        Підвіконня з граніту
                                                    
                                                    
                                                        Підвіконня з мармуру
```

Comment: Please show your code! See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is a low-quality question.